# how to check whether button is present or not in selenium webdriver?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tried with below code,

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).isDisplayed()) 
{
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).click();
}

else
    System.out.println("Show more is not there");
```

Here, if there is "Show more" button in application, it's executing correctly but when the "Show more" button is not there, it's not executing else part and showing "Unable to locate element error"
Can anyone please help in this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each time you call `.findElement()`, Selenium searches for the element. You would be better off finding the element once, storing it in a variable, and then doing `variableName.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium throws an exception when not able to find and element using findElement so you will need to use `try / catch` blocks -

```
try 
{
     if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).isDisplayed()) 
     {
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).click();
     }
}
catch (ElementNotFoundException | ElementNotVisibleException | NoSuchElementException)
{
    System.out.println("Show more is not there");
}
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)), `.findElements()` is the preferred method.  `findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.`

Answer (score 0):

There are two different methods to find out if a WebElement is present at the page. The first one is to catch the exception like in the other answer or to make a list like:

```
List<WebElement> resultList = findElements(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]"));
```

and then check the size of the list:

```
resultList.size() = 0;
```

so in your example it would be:

```
List<WebElement> resultList = findElements(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]"));
if(resultList.size() > 0){
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).click();
}else{
    System.out.println("Show more is not there");
}
```

Comment: This is correct but you should use `resultList.get(0).click()` instead of finding the element again. You can also use `resultList.isEmpty()` instead of `.size > 0`.

Comment: Yes, exactly, you are right of course.. haven't thought aber this :)